# Random background in php and css

Tags: php, css, html, background

So I am trying to get it do it will choose either 1.jpg 2.jpg or 3.jpg. My guess is I am doing this wrong but I am getting no php errors nor is my IDE telling my that my CSS is wrong, so I have nothing to go on.

Code:

HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
        <?php
            include 'php/backgorundlogic.php';
        ?>
        <style>
            body {
                background:url($bgset);
                background-size:cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input class="searchbar" type="text" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $rbg = mt_rand(1, 3);
    $ext = '.jpg';

    $bgset = 'img/' + $rbg + $ext;
?>
```

DEMO: [here](http://orikina.com)

Comment: Are you sure `$bgset` is a valid image filename ;)

Comment: Just checking, did you intend to include `backgorundlogic.php`, or `backgroundlogic.php`?

Answer (score 4):

use . instead of +

```
<?php
    $rbg = mt_rand(1, 3);
    $ext = '.jpg';

    $bgset = 'img/' . $rbg . $ext;
?>
```

and change this line

```
    <style>
        body {
            background:url(<?php echo $bgset; ?>);
            background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: +1 This is indeed another problem. However, consider explaining the difference between the two operators for the OP's benefit.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
background:url($bgset);
```

Should be this:

```
background:url(<?php echo $bgset ?>);
```

Right now the PHP engine is passing `$bgset` through as plain text since it is not in a PHP script context.  You might consider being a bit more future-proof and HTML-escape the value as well:

```
background:url(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bgset) ?>);
```

Comment: How do I set two answers as the answer?

Comment: @user2014751 You can't. In this case it may be appropriate to refrain from selecting a correct answer unless it addresses all of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: url('<?php $a = array(‘anyfile.jpg’,'anyotherfile.gif’, ‘somefile.png’); echo $a[array_rand($a)];?>');
```

or if your image names conform to something with an integer on the end, eg. clouds3.png

```
 background: url('/images/lm/clouds<?php echo rand(0,10)?>.png') ;
```